# Error "switch" + Peculiarity - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a switch in Python with a peculiarity.

```
OperativeSystems = {"nt": os.system("cls"), "posix": os.system("clear")}
try:
    OperativeSystems[os.name]
except:
    print("Can not clean the screen in the current operating system")
```

I want execute the command to clear the console, but my program execute "cls" and "clear". This is my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
OperativeSystems = {"nt": os.system("cls"), "posix": os.system("clear")}
```

You are invoking os.system when the dictionary is declared at runtime. You probably want to do this

```
OperativeSystems = {"nt": lambda: os.system("cls"), "posix": lambda: os.system("clear")}

OperativeSystems["nt"]()
```

Now doing a lookup will return a lambda (short-cut function) that when invoked will call `os.system`

Answer (score 1):

You are executing both `os.system()` calls in your first line, and what actually gets stored in the dictionary is the return values from the `os.system()` calls. Either only store the parameter to `os.system()` in your dictionary and invoke `os.system(OperativeSystems[os.name])` inside your `try`, or make the dictionary values into lambdas.

Answer (score -1):

```
## First solution

class OperatingSystem:
    OSDict = {
        "nt" : NTOs,
        "posix" : PosixOs
        }
    @staticmethod
    def create_os(self,name):
        return self.OSDict[name]()

class NTos:
    def clear_screen(self):
        os.system("cls")

class PosixOs:
    def clear_screen(self):
        os.system("clear")

OperatingSystem.create_os("nt").clear_screen()
OperatingSystem.create_os("posix").clear_screen()

## Second solution

def clear(os_name):
    if os_name == "nt":
        command = "cls"
    if os_name == "posix":
        command = "clear"
    os.system(command)

clear("nt")
clear("posix")


## Third solution

OperatingSystems = {
    "nt"    : "cls",
    "posix" : "clear"
    }

os.system(OpeartingSystems("nt"))
os.system(OpeartingSystems("posix"))

## Fourth solution

# This is screaming for polymorphisme (solution #1)
OperatingSystems = {
    "nt"    : {"clear_screen":lambda : os.system("cls")}
    "posix" : {"clear_screen":lambda : os.system("clear")}
    }

OperatingSystems["nt"].clear_screen()
```

Comment: that is horribly over complicated its almost java.